Pass Record Id from Hyperlink formula field to screen flow
I need to pass the Record Id from a Hyperlink formula field to a screen flow.
But everytime I click on the hyperlink it's saying invalid URL.
I have tried all the possible alternatives, but it's not working.
Below is my formula. recordId is the screen flow variable.
HYPERLINK("/flow/Update_Order_Fav&recordId=Id","Add Fav","_self")

Please help me on this. Thank you

You've incorrectly constructed the HYPERLINK
HYPERLINK("/flow/Update_Order_Fav&recordId=Id","Add Fav","_self")

The =Id is treated as a string of literal value Id where you want to use the actual record's Id
Hence
HYPERLINK("/flow/Update_Order_Fav&recordId=" & Id,"Add Fav","_self")

is what you need - that is, just like any Text formula field that is a mix of literals and merge fields, these have to be concatenated together

thank you  @cropredy.. it worked :)
